# Handling a failure with mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I implemented an endpoint which has to make changes on the database. I now want to check if the rollback works if something goes wrong during the transaction. I have mocked a success and the next step in the test should mock a test failure. The problem is: If I tell Mockito to throw an exception, I can't check the results later, because then it terminates with the exception. But I want to make sure that the data in the database has not changed. So Mockito should continue, despite failure. How can this be done?

Comment: You can catch the exception in the test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mockito **doThrow()** and want to assert the exception message, you can add the below annotation to you test

```
@Test(expected=MyException.class)
```

This will assert that an exception has occurred.

Else, if your intention is to stub the method which makes database call, you can try using Mockito's **doNothing()**

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(mock).method()
```